# Programming for iOS folder

Tags: ios, api, system, directory, ios6

I don't think it is posible or allowed but I want to confirm one thing.

Is there an API for the iOS folder system which can allow us to add features to it?

The one we use commonly use to keep similar apps together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the Springboard (launch screen) system of arranging apps into folders, then, no, there is no way to interact with that from your program.

Answer (score 1):

Not officially, no. If you do it your app will get rejected for sure.

But developing jailbreak tweaks has it's benefits. You can do it that way and then deploy it through Cydia.